# Scrolling within AS3 Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll, movieclip

I'm trying to scroll a movieclip within flash. The problem is I have buttons within the movieClip so everytime I try to scroll its difficult not to open the button. My code is below for the scroll im using which is fairly simple.

```
ChestBiceps.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ClipDraggedOn); 

var boundsRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(ChestBiceps.x, -200, 0, 310); 

function ClipDraggedOn(event:MouseEvent):void { 

ChestBiceps.startDrag(false, boundsRect); 

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ClipDraggedOff); 

} 

function ClipDraggedOff(event:MouseEvent):void { 

ChestBiceps.stopDrag(); 

stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ClipDraggedOff); }
```

Could someone try and figure how I disable the buttons almost whilst scrolling? I still want to be able to use the buttons, just not when scrolling...Thanks in advance

Comment: The buttons are within the ChestBiceps movieclip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the buttons add the following:

```
        function ClipDraggedOn(event:MouseEvent):void {

            ChestBiceps.mouseEnabled = false;
            ChestBiceps.mouseChildren = false;
            [...]
```

To re-enable the buttons add the following:

```
        function ClipDraggedOff(event:MouseEvent):void {

            ChestBiceps.mouseEnabled = true;
            ChestBiceps.mouseChildren = true;
            [...]
```

Comment: thanks man that seems to work nicely by stopping it from selecting buttons whilst scrolling, the problem now is cant select the buttons at all. Ive included the code to re-enable the buttons and it doesnt seem to respond to it...